# Comparing and getting the indexes of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, indexing

What would be a numpy function that goes through array `a` and then output the indexes where values of array `b` is allocated.

Code:

```
a = np.array(["BTCUSD", "ETHUSDC", "BBB", "ETHUSD", "cow", "head"])
b=  np.array(["BTCUSD", "ETHUSD"])
```

Expected output:

```
Indexes: 0, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[list(a).index(i) for i in a if i in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.nonzero(a == b[:, None])[1]
```